# Quick command accessing mutlidimensional array elements from list with wanted indices

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering if anybody knows of a quick way to obtain the elements of a 2D array from a list of given indices?

The following code do what I want, but I am wondering if there is some quicker way to do the operation in the loop in the code below? What I am looking for is a command like array[wantedIndices] instead of the loop in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.arange(0, 1+.1, .25)
y = np.arange(0, 1+.1, .25)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print('\n x \n', x,)

index = [(np.random.randint(0, high=len(x)), np.random.randint(0, high=len(x))) for i in range(len(x))]
print('\n index \n', index)

for indexNumber in range(len(index)):
    print('\n index[%d]:' %indexNumber, index[indexNumber], '\n x[index[%d]] \n' %indexNumber, x[index[indexNumber]])
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
x 
 [[0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]]

 index 
 [(3, 4), (0, 1), (3, 0), (0, 1), (4, 4)]

 index[0]: (3, 4) 
 x[index[0]] 
 1.0

 index[1]: (0, 1) 
 x[index[1]] 
 0.25

 index[2]: (3, 0) 
 x[index[2]] 
 0.0

 index[3]: (0, 1) 
 x[index[3]] 
 0.25

 index[4]: (4, 4) 
 x[index[4]] 
 1.0
```

Comment: `idx=np.array(index)` followed by `x[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, hpaulj!